# Weird russet potato?

Tags: food-safety, potatoes

I'm supposed to be boiling it, but this russet potato has this one smooth spot on it. It's not like the rest of the potato's texture, it's almost as smooth as my phone screen. Not oddly colored. Is this okay to eat?

[image: potatoshinyspotrusset]

(Click to enlarge)

Answer (score 3):

I would guess it might just have leaned against a stone as it grew, the texture difference would be from the skin reacting to something pressing on it if so.  Or it might be a scar that's healed over.  I've seen lots of garden-grown potatoes with imperfections, they're usually not a problem.

It is probably safe to eat if there's no interior discoloration or other signs of trouble.  If you're really unsure, you can peel the potato, or just slice the peel off in that area.

Comment: That was exactly my first thought too; that potato wouldn't bother me in the slightest unless it also seemed weird deep inside the peel.